# Worklight Console does not show new changes to project -- seems to use original code

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am running Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 with Worklight Studio 6.2...

I have made changes to my Worklight project.  For some reason, I cannot get these changes to be seen/previewed when opening in the Worklight Console...

I have made simple changes such as adding print (console.log) statements to see if these changes are making it out to the console...  I have even removed design elements to see if I can get this preview to error out...

Here is what I do:

1. Highlight the app folder (the folder under the "apps" folder) and right-click
2. Select Run As > 2 Build All Environments
3. Once that is complete, I highlight the project folder (the topmost folder in the project)  and right-click, selecting Open Worklight Console, which opens the console in Firefox
4. Click the Preview as Common Resources link in the Console
5. The "old" code/project runs -- no changes appear

I have tried Cleaning the project, closing and re-opening Eclipse, rebooting my machine, etc. but nothing seems to shake this up.  Worklight seems to use the "old" code no matter what I do in Eclipse...

Is there a setting on Worklight I may be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting Worklight 6.2 you do not need to either build or deploy your application in order to see changes made to web resources.

The following should suffice:

1. Create a Project and application
2. Run As > Run on Worklight Development Environment
3. Open console, view the application (keep this tab open)
4. In Eclipse, change some resource (image, CSS, HTML, JavaScript)
5. Return to the previously opened tab and refresh it

The change should be visible to you.

Something to try:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Open your TMPDIR and delete the wlBuildResources folder
3. Open Eclipse, try again
4. You can also try adding a mobile environment to your application; there are some reports this some times, show how, helps 'refreshing' the web resources used while previewing applications
5. You can also make sure you are using the very latest 6.2.0.01 iFix; there were preview-related fixes in the past. You can get it from IBM Fix Central website (assuming you are an IBM customer/business partner; for evaluation purposes you should download the latest available version, from the Eclipse Marketplace - v6.3)

Note that Run As > Build all environment does not actually deploy your modified web resources to the server, it only generates the .wlapp for later consumption elsewhere, so I suggest to follow my steps at the very top of this answer, by using Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server, and later on simply save (ctrl/cmd-s) and then go to the console to verify the changes are there.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I went through you steps above, but in Mac OS I could not find the $TMPDIR.  I tried this -- http://superuser.com/questions/581347/where-is-the-temp-folder-in-os-x -- but it did not find any temp directory.  However, I rebooted my machine and all seems to be working now.

Comment: In Mac, you can find it by opening Terminal and typing "open $TMPDIR".